# Как получить имя всех button окна FindWindowEx

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, hook

Сколько ищу, не могу найти ответ на этот вопрос.
пробовал вот это, но не работает(

```
IntPtr hWndButton = FindWindowEx(h, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Читаем https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx .

Comment: Скорее всего ваш класс равен не "Button" а "BUTTON" (если кнопка стандартная), а может быть и вовсе какой-нибудь другой (зависит от вашего движка). Например "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a"

Comment: UI Automation решит все ваши проблемы. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall(v=vs.110).aspx